# Vertical Align Middle in Wordpress table

Tags: html, css, wordpress, html-table

I'm working on a Wordpress.org site with a plugin that allows me to change the source of a footer area, as my theme does not support a footer. I'm trying to create a table with a logo and 2 PHP elements that display scrolling logos of our sponsors and partners.

In short, the table should look like this:

```
---------------------------------------------
|           |               |               |
|           | Our Partners  |(PARTNERS PHP) |
|           |               |               |
|   (LOGO)  |---------------|---------------|
|           |               |               |
|           | Our Sponsors  |(SPONSORS PHP) |
|           |               |               |
---------------------------------------------
```

However, I am having issues getting the text saying 'Our Partners' and 'Our Sponsors to align vertically. I suspect the issue may be with Wordpress's styling.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
<style>
    #footer_table_layout {
        width: 100%;
    }
    #shoutouts {
        width: 100%;
    }
    #label {
        vertical-align: middle !important;
    }
    #logo {
      vertical-align: middle;
      width: 20%;
    }
</style>

<table id="footer_table_layout">

    <tr id="shoutouts">
        <td rowspan=2 id="logo"><img src="/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/logo5.png" /></td>
        <td><h3 id="label">Our Partners</h3></td>
        <td><?php kw_sc_logo_carousel('partners'); ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="shoutouts">
        <td><h3 id="label">Our Sponsors</h3></td>
        <td><?php kw_sc_logo_carousel('sponsors'); ?></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: [This](https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/vertical-centering/) article might help you

Comment: @flosommerfeld It did - could you please post that as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> With Flexbox, you can stop worrying. You can align anything (vertically or horizontally) quite painlessly with the align-items, align-self, and justify-content properties.

[This arcticle](https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/vertical-centering/) will help you with vertical centering by using Flexbox.

Answer (score 1):

Apply the vertical-align attribute to the table cell instead i.e.

```
#shoutouts{
     vertical-align: middle;
}
```

This should instruct it to vertically align its contents